# Effect on Electric Field due to partially placed dielectric in capacitor

Tags: electrostatics

[image: Fig. 1]

Initially suppose, there is no dielectric object(brown rectangle) present in capacitor. The charge density on left plate is **+σ** and on right plate **-σ**. It is clear that electric field due to both plates is **σ/ε** in right direction in between capacitor.

---

Now, place a dielectric object as shown in Fig. partially. The dielectric will get polarize. I have read that at point A and point B still have **σ/ε** as electric field in right direction.
***Question:*** Why Electric Field at point A and point B are unaffected? Why doesn't it decrease due to the presence of dielectric medium?
**ε = epsilon knot*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The electric field is unaffected because you still apply Gauss's law the same way you would normally do outside the dielectric, with the same result. You can visualize the E-field lines starting at the positively charged plate on the left and terminating at the negatively charged plate on the right. The charge density on the plates are the same, and thus so is the E-field outside the dielectric.

The polarization charges induced in the dielectric do affect the E-field inside the dielectric, but the E-field due to these charges cancel out outside the dielectric.